# My emulator opens as below, but I want it to open in phone view. How can I achieve this?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My emulator opens as below, but I want it to open in phone view. How can I achieve this?
[image]

example :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is the second screenshot of a emulator on a Windows device? I noticed that the first screenshot is on a Mac. (Assuming that is the platform where the issue is.) Try running the emulator in the emulator tab in Android Studio.

[image: Emulator running inside tool window]

This is the only way I have found that enables you to run an emulator with a phone-profile hardware style on a Mac.

Comment: unfortunately this is not what i want, i want emulator to work as phone outside android studio

Comment: Run your project on a Windows machine then. Its the only other option

Comment: This is not the answer to my question.

Comment: I told you the only solution. macOS's windowing system is just not supportive of that kind of window. Have you ever seen a customized window type at all in macOS? No. How about Windows? Yes. An emulator window like you want is technically not achievable on macOS. It would be also a greater help if you could clarify the question, like which OS you are on, which emulator version you're trying to run, and which version of Android Studio you have left.

Comment: Dear friend, I have been using an emulator as I wanted for a long time, but whatever happened, now my emulator opens like this. I am using macOS operating system. @PIRUX

Comment: Have you updated macOS recently? Which version are you running?

Comment: Why do you want the emulator to look like a phone? Why do you care? It should make no difference unless you're trying to take screenshots including the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
On the 'Emulator' tab, Click on the 'Gear' icon, select 'View Mode', then choose 'Float'.

Solution 2:
Go to File >> Settings >> Tools >> Emulator >> Uncheck 'Launch in a tool window'